# Firefox not reading background of nested element

Tags: html, css, firefox

I encountered a strange issue with Firefox, I'm creating a menu with maximum three levels, and everything is working fine in chrome, but in Firefox after I click on 'First Level Menu', there opens a ul with two elements, and when I click on 'Second Level Menu', and suddenly the background-color from this element (gray) disappears and it's dark grey.

CSS:

```
.leftpanel
{
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #282828;
}

.leftpanel>ul
{
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.leftpanel li
{
    width: 230px;
}

.leftpanel li>a
{
    display: block;
}
.leftpanel ul a 
{ 
    color: #999; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    font-size: 13px; 
}
.leftpanel ul a span { margin-right: 10px; }
.leftpanel ul > li > a { border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #232323; }
.leftpanel ul > li > a:hover,
.leftpanel ul > li > a:focus { background-color: #2c2c2c; color: #fff; border-bottom-color: #232323; }
.leftpanel ul > li { margin-bottom: 0; }


.leftpanel ul > li.expand ul { background: #eee; }
.leftpanel ul > li.expand > a {
    background-image: url(../images/droparrow.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right 19px; }

.leftpanel ul .expand ul li a  {
    display: block; font-size: 13px; padding: 7px 10px 7px 30px; color: #333;  
}
.leftpanel ul .expand ul li a:hover { text-decoration: none; background-color: #fff; color: black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
.leftpanel ul .expand ul ul li { border-right: 0; }
.leftpanel ul .expand ul ul li a { padding-left: 40px;}

.leftpanel ul > li.active > a { background-color: #5c0154 ; color: #fff; }
.leftpanel ul > li.active > a:hover { background-color: #5c0154; }
.leftpanel ul .expand ul li.active a { background-color: #972f8e; color: white; }
```

HTML part where it happens:

```
<li class="expand">
                <a href="#">First Level Menu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="expand">
                        <a href="#">Second Level Menu</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="page3.html">Third Level Menu</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="bla.html">Another Third Level Menu</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="expand">
                        <a href="#">Another Second Level Menu</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="bla.html">Third Level Menu</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="bla.html">Another Third Level Menu</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/qWLTS/

Can someone help? It's driving me mad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed these 2 lines from your CSS, and all worked fine on FF, didn't test on chrome though.

```
.leftpanel ul > li > a:hover,
.leftpanel ul > li > a:focus { background-color: #2c2c2c; color: #fff; border-bottom-color: #232323; }
```

Comment: after removing of both lines there disappear effect on hovering of first level, but if I only remove focus it works too :) Thanks, mate! :)